# Read remote file with node.js (http.get)

Tags: node.js

Whats the best way to read a remote file? I want to get the whole file (not chunks).

I started with the following example

```
var get = http.get(options).on('response', function (response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
```

I want to parse the file as csv, however for this I need the whole file rather than chunked data.

Answer (score 114):

I'd use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for this:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Or if you don't need to save to a file first, and you just need to read the CSV into memory, you can do the following:

```
var request = require('request');
request.get('http://www.whatever.com/my.csv', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var csv = body;
        // Continue with your processing here.
    }
});
```

etc.

Comment: any way to do this natively, seems overkill to include a dependancy for one file?

Comment: request is pretty standard, and just wraps these "native" calls in a clean format.

Comment: @Jamie Node is very lightweight and includes almost nothing else than the bare minimum, so unlike in PHP it's really best to get used to using lots of modules. Keeping them up-to-date is easy (because `package.json`) and they are generally very fast.

Comment: I found I needed to set encoding to null when adopting this answer to support image files: request.get({ url: 'www.whatever.com/my.csv', encoding: null }, (err, res, body) => { ... })

Comment: Does this wait to save the whole file to memory? How can i stream the incoming data like with pipe() but without writing the data?

Comment: Could more rows be added to the file which is being read here and make the final file available for downloading?

Comment: > "As of Feb 11th 2020, `request` is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected to land. In fact, none have landed for some time."

Comment: What if the site requires a username and password? can you please explain that too?

Answer (score 28):

You can do something like this, without using any external libraries.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");

const file = fs.createWriteStream("data.txt");

https.get("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt", response => {
  var stream = response.pipe(file);

  stream.on("finish", function() {
    console.log("done");
  });
});
```

Comment: What if the site requires a username and password? can you please explain that too?

Comment: Use https://username:password@remote.website

Answer (score 26):

```
http.get(options).on('response', function (response) {
    var body = '';
    var i = 0;
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        i++;
        body += chunk;
        console.log('BODY Part: ' + i);
    });
    response.on('end', function () {

        console.log(body);
        console.log('Finished');
    });
});
```

Changes to this, which works. Any comments?

Comment: What if the site requires a username and password? can you please explain that too?

Answer (score 0):

```
function(url,callback){
    request(url).on('data',(data) => {
        try{
            var json = JSON.parse(data);    
        }
        catch(error){
            callback("");
        }
        callback(json);
    })
}
```

You can also use this. This is to async flow. The error comes when the response is not a JSON. Also in 404 status code .