# Check Existence of a file located in some http link in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, file-exists

I have a file in http://example.com/test.csv. How can I will check whether the file exists or not in Node.js. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)? (hint: fs.exists might help)

Comment: fs.exits works if file path is in local server.But in my case file is in remote server ie http://xxxxxx.com/test.csv

Comment: You'll need to download it to check or use a `HEAD` check.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14552721/95190

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way, would be to perform HTTP GET request to that URI, is response is 200 OK, file exist, otherwise it's not.

[request.js](https://github.com/mikeal/request) could be handy in that case, code:

```
var request = require('request'); // include request module
request('http://xxxxxx.com/test.csv', function (err, resp) {
   if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
      return // file exist
   }

   // file does not exist
});
```

Comment: Also, it would be nice to check an existence of web content without need of downloading it.

Answer (score 3):

A little late on this, but why not just use `http`?  This method should only download the headers and not the whole file.

```
// Import HTTP module
var http = require ("http");

// Set request options
var options = { method: "HEAD", host: "example.com", port: 80, path: "test.csv" };
// Initialize HTTP request
var request = http.request ( options, function ( response ) {
    console.log ( "Status Code: " + response.statusCode );
});
// End request
request.end ();
```