# Create a Read Stream remotely without writing it node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer

I'm trying to create a Read Stream from a remote file without writing it to disc.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('Video.mp4');
var request = http.get('http://url.tld/video.mp4', function(response){
        response.pipe(file);
});
```

Can I create a Read Stream directly from an HTTP response without writing it to disc ? Maybe creating a buffer in chunks and covert it to readable stream ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module.

Have a look at 7zark7's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552721/7189461