# Read a json file from requesting Url

Tags: node.js, express

I m trying to extract data from this url

> https://twitter.com/i/tfb/v1/tweet_activity/web/poll/968074591301140480

When i hit this url in browser is start downloading a `.json` file.

But i want to read this data in node.js.

I m stuck in this. 
Please, Help me out.

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552638/read-remote-file-with-node-js-http-get

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well easy enough, Just download the file and do this:

```
var json = require('./yourfile.json');
```

Node will automatically parse this json and now you can access it.

```
console.log(json);
```

[image: Here's one example, i did myself.]

Now, If you want to do this dynamically by that i mean for user in node.js:

You can do it like this:

First install an http middleware, such as node-fetch

```
npm install node-fetch
```

Now you'd go into node and run this up:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');



fetch(`https://twitter.com/i/tfb/v1/tweet_activity/web/poll/USER_ID_HERE`)
.then(res => res.json)
.then((json) => {
      // u have your json here now, u can use it here.
 })
```

Comment: No, I cant do so. As the Url will change for each user. Need to dynamically download and read the data.