# Node readline http get

Tags: node.js

I want to read line by line through an http file using Node. I really like using the readline module to go through a normal file using something like the following:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var myInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('demofile1.html')
});

var lineno = 0;
myInterface.on('line', function (line) {
  lineno++;
  console.log('Line number ' + lineno + ': ' + line);
});
```

I can also get an http file with something like the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Obviously I can combine the two by first saving to a file and then reading it but this feels like a bit of a waste as I believe that it should be possible to pipe the http response to readLine without involving the filesystem. I just have no idea how to create a "readStream" for the http response.

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552638/read-remote-file-with-node-js-http-get

Answer (score 2):

Ok so you can actually do the following which was probably obvious I guess:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var http = require('http');

var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J--aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  var myInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: response
  });

  ...
});
```