# fetching mp3 file from MeteorJS and trying to convert it into a Blob so that I can play it

Tags: meteor, blob, audio-streaming

am playing around with downloading and serving mp3 files in Meteor.

I am trying to download an MP3 file (https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3) on my MeteorJS Server side (to circumvent CORS issues) and then pass it back to the client to play it in a AUDIO tag.

In Meteor you use the `Meteor.call` function to call a server method. There is not much to configure, it's just a method call and a callback.

When I run the method I receive this:

`` content:
"ID3���@K `�)�<H�   e0�)������1������J}��e����2L����������fȹ\�CO��ȹ'�����}$A�Lݓ����3D/����fĳw��+�LF�$?��`R�l�YA:A��@�0��pq����4�.W"�P���2.Iƭ5��_I�d7d����L��p0��0A��cA�xc��ٲR�BL8䝠4���T��..etc..",                                                                                                                                                                                           data:null,
headers: {
accept-ranges:"bytes",
connection:"close",
content-length:"443926",
content-type:"audio/mpeg",
date:"Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:36:11 GMT",
last-modified:"Fri, 17 Jun 2016 18:16:53 GMT",
server:"Apache",
statusCode:200 ``

which is the working Mp3 file (the content-length is exactly the same as the file I write to disk on the MeteorJS Server side, and it is playable).

However, my following code doesn't let me convert the response into a BLOB:
```

```
MeteorObservable.call( 'episode.download', episode.url.url ).subscribe( ( result: any )=> {
  console.log( 'response', result);
  let URL = window.URL;

  let blob = new Blob([ result.content ], {type: 'audio/mpeg'} );
  console.log('blob', blob);
  let audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  let audioElement:any  = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  audioElement.setAttribute("src", audioUrl);
  audioElement.play();
})
```

When I run the code, the Blob has the wrong size and is not playable

```
Blob(769806) {size: 769806, type: "audio/mpeg"}
size:769806
type:"audio/mpeg"
__proto__:Blob

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

On the backend I just run a `return  HTTP.get( url );` in the method which is using `import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'`.

I have been trying to use `btoa` or `atob` but that doesn't work and as far as I know it is already a base64 encoded file, right?
I am not sure why the Blob constructor creates a larger file then the source returned from the backend. And I am not sure why it is not playing.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Totally strange, I can confirm this and I tried nearly every possible way, even with the npm request module but no chance. The content however is not base64 encoded but a binary string that needs to be put into an UTF8Array first but this also won't create a blob that represents a playable file. Maybe you open an issue because I think this is related to EJSON which is used to to format content that is sent via ddp to the client.

Comment: I have flagged an issue with the Meteor platform. What I find strange, is that the source code I get back from the server seems to look the same as when I preview the file itself. It starts with ID3?? and seems to end the same way too. But yeah, there must be something wrong with the formatting. Do you reckon there are better ways to stream content to the client? My end goal is to store the binary file in IndexedDB for offline playing. Due to CORS issues I have to route via my Meteor/nodejs Server.

Comment: I prefer ostrio:files and gridfs but that requires you to save the file on the server

Comment: Yeah, I have an example using Mongo's gridFS (https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f) but yeah, I actually just want to proxy them. I am created a tiny nodejs server that does that but I have to see if I can capture it chunked and store it into IndexedDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution that uses `request` instead of Meteor's `HTTP`:

First you need to install `request` and `request-promise-native` in order to make it easy to return your result to clients.

```
$ meteor npm install --save request request-promise-native
```

Now you just return the promise of the request in a Meteor method:

**server/request.js**

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import request from 'request-promise-native'

Meteor.methods({
  getAudio (url) {
    return request.get({url, encoding: null})
  }
})
```

Notice the `encoding: null` flag, which causes the result to be binary. I found this [in a comment of an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552721/3098783) related to downloading binary data via node. This causes not to use string but binary representation of the data (I don't know how but maybe it is a fallback that uses [Node Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)).

Now it gets interesting. On your client you wont receive a complex result anymore but either an Error or a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) which makes sense because Meteor uses [EJSON](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html) to send data over the wires with DDP and the representation of binary data is a Uint8Array as described in the documentation.

Because you can just pass in a Uint8Array into a Blob you can now easily create the blob like so:

```js
const blob = new Blob([utf8Array], {type: 'audio/mpeg'})
```

Summarizing all this into a small template if could look like this:

**client/fetch.html**

```js
<template name="fetch">
    <button id="fetchbutton">Fetch Mp3</button>
    {{#if source}}
        <audio id="player" src={{source}} preload="none" content="audio/mpeg" controls></audio>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

**client/fetch.js**

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'

import './fetch.html'

Template.fetch.onCreated(function helloOnCreated () {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.source = new ReactiveVar(null)
})

Template.fetch.helpers({
  source () {
    return Template.instance().source.get()
  },
})

Template.fetch.events({
  'click #fetchbutton' (event, instance) {
    Meteor.call('getAudio', 'https://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3', (err, uint8Array) => {
      const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], {type: 'audio/mpeg'})
      instance.source.set(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into this issue mate! I did find a way around myself; I added an Express API to my Meteor project (http://www.mhurwi.com/meteor-with-express/) and setup a REST Endpoint that uses `Request` and `Request-progress` to send the files over in chunks. That worked beautifully and does give the same arraybuffer as your solution. Then with Angular you can follow the progress: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is adding a REST endpoint *using Express) to your Meteor backend.
Instead of HTTP we use `request` and `request-progress` to send the data chunked in case of large files.

On the frontend I catch the chunks using https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events to show a loader and deal with the response.

I could listen to the download via

```
this.http.get( 'the URL to a mp3', { responseType: 'arraybuffer'} ).subscribe( ( res:any ) => {
var blob = new Blob( [res], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
} );
```

The above example doesn't show progress by the way, you need to implement the progress-events as explained in the angular article. Happy to update the example to my final code when finished.

The Express setup on the Meteor Server:

```
/* 
  Source:http://www.mhurwi.com/meteor-with-express/
  ## api.class.ts
*/

import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
const express = require('express');
const trackRoute = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const progress = require('request-progress');

export function api() {
  const app = express();

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
  app.use('/episodes', trackRoute);

  trackRoute.get('/:url', (req, res) => {

    res.set('content-type', 'audio/mp3');
    res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');

    // The options argument is optional so you can omit it
    progress(request(req.params.url  ), {
      // throttle: 2000,                    // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms
      // delay: 1000,                       // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms
      // lengthHeader: 'x-transfer-length'  // Length header to use, defaults to content-length
    })
    .on('progress', function (state) {
      // The state is an object that looks like this:
      // {
      //     percent: 0.5,               // Overall percent (between 0 to 1)
      //     speed: 554732,              // The download speed in bytes/sec
      //     size: {
      //         total: 90044871,        // The total payload size in bytes
      //         transferred: 27610959   // The transferred payload size in bytes
      //     },
      //     time: {
      //         elapsed: 36.235,        // The total elapsed seconds since the start (3 decimals)
      //         remaining: 81.403       // The remaining seconds to finish (3 decimals)
      //     }
      // }
      console.log('progress', state);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      // Do something with err
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('DONE');
      // Do something after request finishes
    })
    .pipe(res);

  });
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(app);
}
```

and then add this to your meteor startup:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { api } from './imports/lib/api.class';
Meteor.startup( () => {
   api();
});
```