# How can I parse JavaScript source code from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `archive.json` file like below:

```
  var archive = {
  "archiveList" : [
      { url : "https://ddddd",
          greetings : "blahblahblah"},
      { url :"https://ddd1",
          greetings : "blahblah"},
       .....
  ]
}
```

I use the `var` keyword because I want to read from static page.

Here is the problem.
I want to read that file and update archivelist array.
How can I parse this file?

=============================Add more info================================

What I'm trying to is two things.

1. In static page, Read json(or js object) data from static page and show up
2. In server with node.js, Read json and insert archiveList data

What I read is this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637657/6234242

First thing what I'm trying to is solved, but Second one is my problem.

When I use `module.exports = {...}`, First thing is not working.

=============================Add more info================================

When I load and parse `archive.json` file, console says below.

```
undefined:1
 var archive = {
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: So is it a json or a js object?

Comment: `var myJson = require('path/to/file.json');` doesn't work for you? what have you tried?

Comment: @Art3mix — Since there is no `export`, and it isn't JSON, that wouldn't work.

Comment: I Updated. When I use `export`, First thing what I'm trying to is not working

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing some concepts here, but what you're presenting is plain JS. You can `require` that file if it's in your filesystem. The only real change needed is that you export something from that file:

```
module.exports = {
  "archiveList" : [
    { url : "https://ddddd",
      greetings : "blahblahblah"},
    { url :"https://ddd1",
      greetings : "blahblah"},
    .....
  ]
}
```

After that you can, for example:

```
const archiveList = require('./archiveList.js')
```

That's about it. From the little information you've provided, this should be enough, but otherwise expand on your use case.

Comment: Thank you, I expanded on my use case. When I use `module.exports`, first thing what i'm trying to is not working. The browser says `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Comment: Wait, are you doing this in browser or in Node?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is local, use:

`module.exports = {
  "archiveList" : [`

to export the object from the static file, then add

`const list = require('./file.js')`

to your application.

Comment: I Updated. Thank you but when I use export, First thing what I'm trying to is not working.

Comment: so its a web page not a local file, if so try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/14552721/10775453

Comment: Nope file is in local, And What I'm trying to is two things. please read again

Comment: `var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8'));`
for more information read: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: don't forget to replact %file% with file path, hope it helps

Comment: My problem is not loading file, but parsing that js object file without breaking down first thing what I want (load js object in browser and append data)