# How to read xml file content with vuejs Server side?

Tags: javascript, xml, vue.js, filereader

I need to read a xml file storaged in a specifice path in server side.. I am using the VueJS and I can-t use JQUERY... could you help me with some idea or advice?

Case:
1. The file will be storage in /static/label/custom-label.xml
2. I need to read this file of the server side and load the contect.
3. I will use the content loaded in a const.

Comment: Ok, I found a way fast to solver my problem
`getLabelXml() {
        let result = null;
        const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET', '/label/paciente.label', false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          result = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return result;
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not sure what backend you're using, but it's flagged as JS so I'll assume Node/Express. Correct me if I'm wrong.*

Use express middleware to define your paths. If you're storing assets on your server for public consumption, store them in your `/public/` folder.

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('files'));
```

Use `/static/` route to get static resources

```
http://localhost:3000/static/foobar.jpg
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

This SO post may help: [Read remote file with node.js (http.get)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552638/read-remote-file-with-node-js-http-get)

Comment: Thanks Peter... I found another way, but your solution was helpful.

Comment: Ah.. my solution was 

`getLabelXml() {
        let result = null;
        const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET', '/label/paciente.label', false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          /result = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return result;
      }`