# How can I render and display pdf to client without force download with pipe()

Tags: node.js, express

I'm doing a API request that sends a PDF file as response, but when the route is accessed, the file is immediately force downloaded. I just want to display a PDF file inside a client browser, without downloading it.

```
exports.print = (req,res) => {
    request("API").on('response', function(response) {
        res.set({
            'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=my.pdf',
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        });
    })
    .pipe(res);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. can you please try that code?

Comment: could you please tell me whether the given answer is working or not atleast?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://gist.github.com/adamgibbons/af2de54c011e68a7b85a zishon89 answer, it should do the job.

```
var express = require('express'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        app = express();
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        var filePath = "/files/my_pdf_file.pdf";

        fs.readFile(__dirname + filePath , function (err,data){
            res.contentType("application/pdf");
            res.send(data);
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('Listening on 3000');
    });
```

Comment: Hello there! As i said, the pdf file comes from a remote API request so I can't specific file's path: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open: {URL}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552638/read-remote-file-with-node-js-http-get this may be related, you can combine these two answers

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following code it is working fine in chrome browser. Try below code once please.(please install npm request package. You can use async and await also)

I got the pdf from external api and stored it in "test.pdf" after that i am reading that pdf file and sending the data to browser.

```
exports.sendPDFFIle=(req,res)=>{
  request=require('request');
  const fs=require('fs');
  request('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../TestPdf/test.pdf'))

    var data = fs.readFileSync('../TestPdf/test.pdf');
    res.contentType("application/pdf");
    res.send(data);
```

};

Comment: Hello there! As i said, the pdf file comes from a remote API request so I can't specific file's path: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open: {URL}