# multiple packages in http resquest on data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a problem with the http.request in javascript. I am getting multiple packages in the on. ('data'). I understand that it is because the package I am receiving is too large (image). later I pass a .toString('base64').

The question is how can I join the different packages to pass them to the .toString ('base64'). Actually I am trying to put everything in a string but the .toString ('base64') returns something to me that I cannot work with later.

```
var file = req.body.file;
var post_options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/v1/files/' +file,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ BackendToken.access_token
    }
};
var httpg = require('http');
var resultComb ='';    
var post_req = httpg.request(post_options, function(res2) {
    res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
        resultComb += chunk
    });

    res2.on('end', function(){
        var extension = file.split(".").pop()
        var src = ''
        switch (extension.toLowerCase()) {
            case "mp4":
                src = 'data:video/mp4;base64,'
                break
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
            case "png":
                src = 'data:image/png;base64,'
                break
            case "pdf":
                src = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'
                break
        }
        src += resultComb.toString('base64')
        res.json({src:src});
    });
});
```

Comment: seems to be equal to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552638/read-remote-file-with-node-js-http-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is binary, and not a String, is a Buffer. Buffers can't be added with +.

Put them in an array with `.push()` on the `.on('data')` blocks and concatenate them with `Buffer.concat()` on the `.on('end')`block. Then convert the combined buffer.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength

Would be something like:

```
var file = req.body.file;
var post_options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/v1/files/' +file,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ BackendToken.access_token
    }
};
var httpg = require('http');
var resultComb = [];    
var post_req = httpg.request(post_options, function(res2) {
    res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
        resultComb.push(chunk);
    });

    res2.on('end', function(){
        var extension = file.split(".").pop()
        var src = ''
        switch (extension.toLowerCase()) {
            case "mp4":
                src = 'data:video/mp4;base64,'
                break
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
            case "png":
                src = 'data:image/png;base64,'
                break
            case "pdf":
                src = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'
                break
        }
        src += Buffer.concat(resultComb).toString('base64')
        res.json({src:src});
    });
});
```